# passProps throws 'Error calling RCTEventEmiter.receiveTouches' (react-native-navigation)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to pass some data to a modal screen with react-native-navigation pacakage 1.1.65 (https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

**I have two cases** :

### First one

```
export default class SearchTab extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
        dicoDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(realm.objects('User')),
        searchText:'',
        data:[]
  }
}

onPressButton() {
var resultData = this.state.data;
  if(resultData.length > 0){
        console.log("RESULTDATA", resultData);
        this.props.navigator.showModal({
          title: "Modal",
          screen: "App.SearchResult",
          passProps: {
            result: resultData,
          }
        });
  }
}
```

When I clicked the button, it fires me this error :

> 'Error calling RCTEventEmiter.receiveTouches'

The log "RESULTDATA" is something like that with one or several items :

```
    RESULTDATA', { '0': 
        { id: 1,
          name: 'Leanne Graham',
          username: 'Bret',
          email: 'Sincere@april.biz' 
} }
```

### Second one

```
export default class SearchTab extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
        dicoDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(realm.objects('User')),
        searchText:'',
        data:[]
  }
}

onPressButton() {
var resultData = this.state.data;
  if(resultData.length > 0){
        console.log("RESULTDATA", resultData);
        this.props.navigator.showModal({
          title: "Modal",
          screen: "App.SearchResult",
          passProps: {
            result: resultData.name, <== HERE THE ONLY DIFFERENCE
          }
        });
  }
}
```

With this code, the modal screen shows up but when I log `this.props.result` it shows `undefined`.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("PROPS", this.props.result);
  }
```

I would like to use this data to make a ListView in the modal screen which works fine.

No idea what to do with that. I already tested separately some UI elements and with different combinations like described above.

And I want to have the first one to work.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Nobody ?

**EDIT 2**

Here my SearchResult class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  TextInput,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import realm from '../realmDB/realm';
import { ListView } from 'realm/react-native';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

export default class SearchResult extends Component {
  static navigatorStyle = {
    leftButtons: [{
      title: 'Close',
      id: 'close'
    }]
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
        resultDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.result),
        searchText:'',
        data:[]
    }
  }

renderRow(rowData, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow){
    return(
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.username}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput style = {styles.searchText}
            placeholder="Type your research"
            autoCorrect={true}
            returnKeyLabel="search"
            underlineColorAndroid="black"
            placeholderTextColor="black"
            value = {this.state.searchText}
            onChange={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.onPressButton(this.state.searchText)}>
            <Text style={styles.button}>SEARCH</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <ListView
          navigator={this.props.navigator}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.state.resultDataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
          renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
          />
        </View>
      );
```

I also open an issue here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was not a context losing problem. It was about the data structure I used. I had to make nested objects in order to pass the data.
I was trying to pass a wrong format/structure of data that react-native-navigation package did not allow. Only an object can be passed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are passing the 'result' props from the 'App.SearchResult' to the 'SearchTab' component when you are rendering it in the screen component.

Comment: What do you mean ? I try to pass 'result' from 'SearchTab' to 'SearchResult' and not the other way. I don't really get it :)

Comment: @KSoze Share the code of `App.SearchResult` screen component. In that screen component, where you render `SearchTab`, you must pass the `result` object as a prop.

Comment: see my second Edit